# Stack size for fragment transaction

Tags: android

A fragment is launched from activity with a button. This fragment is launched dynamically. I try to see what is happen with fragment stack.

```
launchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment newFragment = new SomeFragment();
            // consider using Java coding conventions (upper first char class names!!!)
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.frame_container, newFragment);
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            transaction.addToBackStack("add_fragment");
            transaction.commit();
            int entryCount = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
            Log.d("New size ", String.valueOf(entryCount));
        }
    });
```

Value of entryCount is mantain zero in the end, and I am curious why.

A second question is how can be return from some fragment, launched in this way from some activity, to the initial activity.

Answer (score 2):

[commit()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit()) method is not called immediately, use [commitNow()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commitNow()) if you want to have `FragmentTransaction` be completed immediately.

To hide a fragment, you can use [hide()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#hide(android.app.Fragment)) method.